# pdb symbol reader could not be loaded

Tags: c#, remote-debugging

In my current machine I have Visual Studio 2017(Windows 10 Pro), I tried to use Remote Debugger tool in my Remote machine (Windows 7 Pro).

I installed x64 Remote Debugger Tool in my Remote machine. I could able to debug the remote machine .exe file, now the concern is both from the remote application as well as the code from my local machine, **breakpoint doesn't hit**, the reason is

> PDB Symbol reader could not be loaded"(for the exe, mscorblib.dll, System.Core.dll,System.dll,System.Xml.Linq.dll,System.Xml.dll,Microsoft.Csharp.dll,System.Configuration.dll,System.Dynamic.dll)(Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly - Binary was not built with debug information)`

manually tired to load the pdb file got `A matching symbol file was not found in this folder`, even though I could able to see the PDB file in the bin/obj folder.

Comment: I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 and installed again , the error got resolved.

Comment: Repairing Visual Studio, also fixed the problem for me.